exception = {FlutterError} Unable to load asset:
I know this kind of questions has already been asked, but I still can't find the solution.
I'm getting flag images from the server and getting this exception, but the flag images can still be loaded.

Unable to load asset: "https://***.com/content/icons/AE.png".
The asset does not exist or has empty data.

I checked my pubspec.yaml file as well but it seems to be fine
Here is my pubspec.yamlfile
name: 
description: "A new Flutter project."

version: 1.0.1+5


environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  camera: ^0.10.5+9
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1

  http: ^1.2.0

  image_picker: ^1.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


dependency_overrides:
  intl: any

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/svg/
    - assets/png/

Here is also how i am getting images
 ListView.separated(
                        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(color: Color(0XFFDCDFEA)),
                        itemCount: controller.countryList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                          var item = controller.countryList[position];
                          return ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                            dense: false,
                            leading: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(color: const Color(0xffA0A0A0).withOpacity(0.2), blurRadius: 25),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(

                                imageUrl: item.icon,
                                height: 25.r,
                                width: 33.r,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                    SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/ic_flag_placeholder.svg'),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                    SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/ic_flag_placeholder.svg'),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () => controller.onCountrySelectedAndMove(item),
                            title: Text(
                              item.countryName,
                              style: AppTextTheme.so4_12(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )


The problem seems to be in the api's response to get the image from your server, which returns an error or empty data.
Have you checked in the network calls to see if the response has status code 200?
If the api to obtain the image is protected, consider adding the token in the request headers.
